# How to dynamically set the value to a static parameter in Struts 2

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, ognl, xml-configuration

I was wondering, is it possible to dynamically set value to static parameter

```xml
<action name="TestApp_*" class="test.TestApp" method="{1}">
   <param name="app_Id">Dynamic value here</param>
   <result name="input">WEB-INF/jsp/test/testView.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I tried

```xml
<action name="TestApp_*" class="test.TestApp" method="{1}">
   <param name="app_Id">${app_Id}</param>
   <result name="input">WEB-INF/jsp/test/testView.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Not working. It shows `${app_Id}` as regular text.

Comment: What do you mean by "showing it as regular text"?

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what exactly you mean by It shows `${app_Id}` as regular text.Struts2 provide this flexibility where you can set `param` values dynamically.

All you need to set these values in your action class and you are all set to use them as a place holder.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
   private int app_Id;

   public String execute() {
      // you execute logic

      this.app_Id= 123;
      return SUCCESS;
   }

 // getter and setter for app_Id
}
```

And you can use this `app_Id` in your result configuration

```
 <action name="TestApp_*" class="test.TestApp" method="{1}">
       <param name="app_Id">${app_Id}</param>
       <result name="input">WEB-INF/jsp/test/testView.jsp</result>
</action>
```

you can get more details [parameters-in-configuration-results](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html)

Comment: But still. It's not working when I tried setting value to it but no use. By 'as regular text' means that <s:property /> displays '${app_Id}'

Comment: i am not sure what you trying to do here? if you want to see that value in jsp `<s:property value="app_id">` should display the value

Comment: Okay, Let me explain. Normally defining parameter in the result is working fine. What i wanna do is define dynamic global parameter for this action.

Comment: Define "global". Global to all the methods of *that* Action ?

Comment: @StormRider:can you define what you mean by global as asked by Andrea

Comment: Ok, I saw this tutorial by mkyoung. Here's the link : http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-configure-static-parameter-for-action-class/ . And i was wondering if i could possibly redefine static variables. Not predefined.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have written (erroneusly) the getter by hand, instead of letting the IDE do it for you.

A variable `app_Id;` must have a getter `getApp_Id()`, while you could have something like `getapp_Id()` or `get_app_Id()`... but how are we supposed to know it if you don't post your Action code ?!

Also, consider to change your variables (from now on) to respect the convention, that wants them camelCased, instead that underscore-separated... then `appId` for the variable and `getAppId()` for the getter.

Comment: I did use IDE to generate getter/setter.

Comment: please post the Java part

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this way..

```
<result type="redirect">
    <param name="location">WEB-INF/jsp/test/testView.jsp</param>
    <param name="inputName">app_Id</param>
</result>
```

in the jsp page you can directly use this value like

```
<s:properties value="app_Id">
```

try this.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [`staticParams` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/static-parameters-interceptor.html).

> This interceptor populates the action with the static parameters defined in the action configuration. If the action implements `Parameterizable`, a map of the static parameters will be also be passed directly to the action. The static params will be added to the request params map, unless `merge` is set to `false`.
>
> Parameters are typically defined with `<param>` elements within `struts.xml`.

It shows how to configure this interceptor to your action configuration.

**For example:**

```xml
<action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
         <param name="staticParams.parse">true</param>
         <param name="staticParams.overwrite">false</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <param name="num">${numValue}</param>
    <result name="success">good_result.ftl</result>
</action>
```

This enables the interceptor to *parse* parameter values for OGNL expression from the action configuration.